# Get the key and value of Map that is used Inside another Map (JAVA)

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I am using a map inside another map, The key of the outer map is Integer and the value is another Map. I get the values as expected but I don't know how to get the key and value of teh inner map. 
Here is the code

```
Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Integer>> cellsMap = new HashMap<Integer, Map<Integer, Integer>>();
Map<Integer , Integer> bandForCell = cellsMap.get(band_number);
    if (bandForCell == null) 
        bandForCell = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    bandForCell.put(erfcn, cell_found);
    cellsMap.put(band_number, bandForCell);

  csv.writeCells((Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Integer>>) cellsMap);

public void writeCells (Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Integer>> cellsMap ) throws IOException
{
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Map<Integer, Integer>> entry : cellsMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Key: " + entry.getKey() + ". Value: " + entry.getValue() + "\n");
    }           
}
```

Out put of my Map

```
Key: 20 Value: {6331=0, 6330=1, 6329=1, 6328=0, 6335=1, 6437=0, 6436=1}
```

The value in the above output is another map.
How can I get the key and value of the inner map from the value of the outer map?

Like Keys of inner map = 6331, 6330, 6329 ....
and values of inner map = 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 ...

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me , Hope it will help someone else in future

```
 for (Map.Entry<Integer, Map<Integer, Integer>> outer : cellsMap.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Key: " + outer.getKey() +  "\n");
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> inner : entry.getValue().entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Key = " + inner.getKey() + ", Value = " + inner.getValue());
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a reference to an inner map, you would just use `cellsMap.get(key)`.  I'm not sure exactly what you want to do, but, for example, if you wanted to get the value where the first key was `i` and the second key was `j`, you could get it using `cellsMap.get(i).get(j)`

Or, if you wanted to print out all the keys and values of the inner map at index `i`, you could use

```
for (Map.Entry> entry : cellsMap.get(i).entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Key: " + entry.getKey() + ". Value: " + entry.getValue() + "\n");
    }
```

Comment: I is the key for the first map.  In order to get one of the second level maps, you need a key to look it up!  if you could be more specific about what you need to do, I could help you better :)

Comment: What I need is to get the key of the outer map , and then the value of the outer map and the value of the outer map is another map so i want to get value of the outer map as separate key and value of the inner map... hope it helped